# How canon are the comics?

Tags: star-trek, comics, canon

When I read the new Star Trek comics (for the Kelvin timeline) I wondered only one thing: **How canon are they?** (in regards to the film-series)

Comment: I've reopened. Although this is superficially a dupe of the [other trek canonicity question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/are-there-levels-of-canon-in-star-trek-like-in-star-wars), this one specifically asks *how* canon they are (and by extension, why) which the dupe doesn't cover, other than to state that they are canon.

Comment: ok good point there (wasn't sure myself if that would be different enough).

Comment: I’d say about five. They’re five canon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're considered canon.

> Like the Countdown comics from 2009, the current ongoing Star Trek comics are considered canon. This means Gary Mitchell is out for Cumberbatch’s Star Trek 2 villain. (It also means Landru is out too, but we don’t hear anyone crying about that one.)

[Straight from Roberto Orci: Current Trek Comics are Canon!](http://www.tor.com/2012/07/18/straight-from-roberto-orci-current-trek-comics-are-canon/)

And the quote from the actual interview:

> Roberto Orci: OK, based on that then with you Anthony Pascale as a witness, I hereby declare anything that we oversee to be canon.

[Exclusive: Orci Says Star Trek TV Talks Getting Real + Declares Movie Tie-in Comics & Game As Canon](http://trekmovie.com/2012/07/17/exclusive-orci-says-star-trek-tv-talks-getting-real-declares-movie-tie-in-comics-game-as-canon/)

See also: [Are There Levels of Canon in Star Trek, Like in Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/are-there-levels-of-canon-in-star-trek-like-in-star-wars)