# Canonicity of some material in "Spock must die!" by James Blish?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, james-blish

[Spock must die!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock_Must_Die!) was a 1970 Star Trek novel by James Blish. I read it as a kid and reread it recently after coming across a used copy. It was an enjoyable read as long as I stayed determined not to let myself focus on some of the silly and nonsensical stuff that cropped up here and there.

The novel introduces some interesting material that I didn't recall ever seeing in the TV and movie incarnations of the franchise. Some of this seems clearly disconfirmed by more canonical stories, but what about the following?

- McCoy is given a backstory in which he joins starfleet after a divorce.
- Chapel has some sort of similar vaguely defined romantic backstory.
- Multiple human women on the ship, not just Chapel, are said to desire Spock romantically or sexually.

Some other stuff seems totally inconsistent with canon, although I could be wrong:

- Kirk is described as having been a starship officer and captain for longer than seems possible given his mid-30's age as portrayed in the TV ToS.
- The Klingons are locked up in some sort of metaphysical jail for 1000 years.
- Rand is portrayed as more of a Maturin to Kirk's Aubrey, rather than as a nameless ensign whom he barely considers worthy of attention.
- Starships under warp drive are described as having their geometrical shapes weirdly distorted as seen by eye.
- There is some description of how in space, it's incredibly hard to engage the enemy in a naval battle. (This seems scientifically sensible but obviously not much like the TV and movie depictions.)

Comment: The McCoy divorce thing at least came up in the reboot series (where it was the source of his nickname, as his ex-wife only left him with his bones).

Comment: And the distortion under warp drive seems at least slightly confirmed by the TOS opening credits.

Comment: Basically a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/who-comes-up-with-all-those-star-trek-facts. None of the books are considered especially canon, nor is there a codified canon that the writers are following (particular post-Nemesis).

Comment: @Valorum - I believe the post Nemesis novels (distinct from novels related to Disco/Picard) are basically their own canon and are consistent in and amongst themselves. The current "Coda" trilogy is basically closing out the post-Nemesis novel 'canon' to make way for novels around the new series.

Comment: May be of interest https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joanna_McCoy https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Jocelyn_Treadway

Comment: @NKCampbell - I was referring to the writers of the new shows (PIC, STD, LOW,  PRO) rather than the writers of the new book series'. It's pretty clear that everything post-Nemesis is its own distinct canon that doesn't particularly relate to the TOS or TNG era shows.

Comment: The book "The Making of Star Trek" by Stephen Whitfield talked about some story ideas for the 3rd season, one of which was McCoy's daughter visiting the Enterprise. I think I remember part of the premise was that McCoy was divorced. Not canonical, but apparently an idea that had been floating around.

Comment: Is *Spock Must Die!* the one with the memorable line from Lt. Uhura "He shouldn't be able to scream in that frequency!"?